# How do I allow a user to browse/choose a file for my app use in Android?

Tags: android, file, browser

I have an app where the user can choose a profile pic using images stored on the phone or SD.

Do I have to write my own file explorer for this?

I've seen a couple examples on anddev, but wasn't sure if there is another way.

Answer (score 7):

Use Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT to launch an activity for the user to select the desired media type.  For selecting an image, you would probably want the MIME type of "image/*".  You also want to wrap this in a choose since often there will be multiple content sources for the user to select from (for example they could browse through the gallery, or could take a picture at that point, or a generic file browser if one is installed, etc).

Here is some rough code, probably buggy because I am just writing it out here:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("image/*");

// Do this if you need to be able to open the returned URI as a stream
// (for example here to read the image data).
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

Intent finalIntent = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select profile picture");

startActivityForResult(finalIntent, IMAGE_SELECTED);
```

When the user has selected something, you will get the selection back in onActivityResult().

More reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_GET_CONTENT

Answer (score 2):

The [OI File Manager](http://www.openintents.org/en/node/159) control is one excellent solution

> The OpenIntents file manager allows
>   you to browse your SD card, create
>   directories, rename, move, and delete
>   files. It also acts as an extension to
>   other applications to display "Open"
>   and "Save" dialogs.